# Show that this matrix is Totally unimodular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, total-unimodularity

Suppose we know that $A \in R^{n\times n}, B\in R^{n\times n}, \begin{bmatrix}a \\ A\end{bmatrix}\in R^{(n+1)\times n}$ and $[b \space B]\in R^{n\times(n+1)}$ are all total unimodular matrix. How can we show that 
$\begin{bmatrix}1 & a^Tb \\ ab^T & AB\end{bmatrix}$ is also TUM? Thanks!

Comment: Begin with the definition of total unimodularity.

Comment: the matrix dimensions do not fit, the block matrix should be something like $\pmatrix{1& a\\b&AB}$.